# Selenium: Get name of actual test method in initialize

Tags: c#, selenium, testing

how can I get name of next Test Method in TestInitialize? I need do know name of the next test method, because I want to set a "name" of actual test method in BrowserStack.
Here is my code:

```
        [TestInitialize]
        public void BeforeAll()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities bsCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("name", /*name*/);
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("os_version", "8");
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("browser", "Firefox");
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("browser_version", "33.0");
            bsCapabilities.SetCapability("resolution", "1024x768");               
            DataCollection.Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), bsCapabilities
            );            
            DataCollection.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(root_site);
            DataCollection.Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [TestMethod]           
        public void ValidLoginTest()
        {                            
            LoginPage LP = new LoginPage();           
            LP.FillForm("agileway", "testwise");
            Assert.IsTrue(Get.Element(FindBy.Id, "flash_notice").Displayed);
        }
```

And in initialize I want a first row something like this:

```
bsCapabilities.SetCapability("name", "ValidLoginTest");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the NUnit Framework to run your tests you should be able to use the [TestContext](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.4) object to get the currently running test's name. Using something like

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name
```

I have used it to great effect in the TearDown method of tests and have just used it in a SetUp method, which also worked.

If you're not using NUnit then maybe take a look at the [TestContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx) Class, this may have a property you can use, such as TestName.